"OpenAI Python API Key Error: 'The api_key client option must be set'
I'm trying to use the OpenAI API in Python to create a chat completion, but I keep running into an error related to the API key. Here's my code:
import os
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Say this is a test",
        }
    ],
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
)

Error message:

openai.OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by
passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY
environment variable


I'm guessing that OPENAI_API_KEY was not found in your environment, so the os.environ.get() call returned null.

How are you setting OPENAI_API_KEY in the environment?
